# Windows won't start if I modify anything on the C partition from a Linux boot disc

Tags: linux, windows

If i start Knoppix Linux from a CD, and then I rename any file or folder on my Windows 7 partition (C), any file at all, including a non-system folder that has nothing to do with Windows, then after rebooting Windows won't start.

I don't remember the exact error message (I know, that's the most important thing), but it was something pretty fundamental about not being able to start the operative system, something corrupt. So I had to reinstall Windows entirely.

Why would any minute modification on the C partition from outside Windows (Linux) would cause Windows to fail to start?

Comment: There isn't a reason. Can you boot into Windows as it is? Or do you get any errors?

Comment: This is certainly not normal behavior: I know of only 1 way to create this situation: You didn't shutdown Windows prior to booting Linux. You hibernated or put it in sleep mode. In that case any change to the Windows partition (or any other partition that holds a Windows pagefile) might completely bork Windows. (Windows doesn't always bring the filesystem in a well defined state.) Windows always assumes it is the only OS installed and so it believes the disk didn't change while it was asleep. Usually a Windows chkdsk will fix the problem, but it can happen Windows is broken beyond repair.

Comment: BubbleMonster: I had to reinstall Windows, there was no way to make it boot. Tonny: I'm pretty sure I did shutdown Windows (no hibernate or sleep). I did the same thing before and Windows used to boot normally afterwards. The only difference now is that my Windows install is a Ghost image, meaning I did not install this Windows but I just put an image of a clean Windows install (that I made myself) on my C. And so it is this Windows that doesn't want to start if I dare modifying anything on the C from Knoppix.

Comment: Which version of Knoppix? Versions from years ago would have been using an older buggy implementation of the `ntfs-3g` FUSE driver. More likely though is Win7 was put into *hybrid sleep* rather than fully shutdown.

Comment: I now use a newer version of Knoppix than I used when I had not this problem. To boot Linux I always click Restart from Windows after inserting Knoppix CD. So I guess Windows was fully shutdown isnt'it ?